# How to set access_control to disallow users having a 'ROLE_USER' to access path: ^/login after successful login?

Tags: symfony, security, symfony-4.2

In `security.yaml` file we define the access control for various routes and the ROLES who can access that same route.

But how can we set the user, who is logged-in but can't revisit the /login page unless and untill it logs out and "ROLE_USER" changes to "anon".

I am new to Symfony 4.2.

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $utils, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
    {
        // to check whether user is looged-in
        if ($authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            die('Logged in user cannot access this page');
        }
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $utils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
            ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        # code...
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you redirect authenticated users from the login page to the start page (or any appropriate page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, in my opinion throwing an `AccessDeniedException` to an already logged in user isn't a good approach. What would your users think? If I have already logged in, why can't I access a page, that I can normally access even if I'm not logged in.

Therefore I'd strongly suggest to redirect logged in users, when accessing the `/login` path, to the start page of your application.

Just adapt the if-condition block in the method `login` of your `SecurityController`:

```
if ($authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)) {
    $this->redirectToRoute('name of the route - replace with an appropriate value');
}
```

You should take care that the route you're redirecting to, doesn't cause another redirect and thus puts you in an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deny access for logged in user to the login page by editing `security.yml`. It is all users of a Symfony app, whether logged in or not, will have the base access privilege: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` and Symfony does not have a exclusive role to not logged in user.

However, you can achieve the same thing by checking whether the user has logged in or not in your controller and perform a redirect or throw an `AccessDeniedException`:

```
public function login($name, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
{
    if ($authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Logged in user cannot access this page');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is the class for AccessDeniedException??

Comment: if statement is incorrect. It should be 'if ($authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Logged in user cannot access this page');
    }'

Comment: Good spot, I copied the example from Symfony doc and haven't edited it.

Comment: What is the class for AccessDeniedException??

Comment: @Saurabh It's from Symfony `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException`

Comment: You mentioned redirect, and that's much better option than throwing an exception. From the UX perspective I think it is terrible to confuse an authenticated user with `AccessDeniedException`.

Comment: @IwanWijaya: yes, I used the same, but it gives me error: 'too many redirects.' and localhost refuse to connect. I have updated my question with controller. Please check